# Umbraco - Editing courier.config kills Courier

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6

Have some issues with courier - After Installing Courier inside the back office it asks you to enter a location, so I enter the location of the second instance of Umbraco.

After logging out and logging back in I do get the extra menu item in content - Good

Also In the back office when I go to Courier section > Locations it shows the URL user id ect - Good

If I open the courier.config and change anything (eg the user id) save the file, then touch the web-config file to force a recompile of the site.

If I go to Courier section > Locations I see this message

```
Location could not be loaded, this could be a configuration error, or because Courier is running in trial mode, and cannot not load locations not on the local machine
```

Even if I go back to the courier.config and change it back to exactly what it was before, it still shows the same error. The only way I have found to fix this is to uninstall and reinstall courier.

Can one one tell me why this happens how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure as to the direction of the question, but this is how you configure the locations within courier.config. User 0 will be the admin user so I'm not sure it is a good idea to change that.

```
 <!-- Repository connection settings -->
 <!-- For each site, a custom repository must be configured, so Courier knows how to connect and authenticate -->
 <repositories>
   <repository name="http://example.co.uk/" alias="http://examplecouk/" type="CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider" visible="true">
     <url>http://example.co.uk/</url>
     <user>0</user>
     <!--
       Alternative, you can specify the specific login / password / encryption values
       <login>admin</login>
       <password>1234</password>
       <passwordEncoding>Clean|Hashed</passwordEncoding>
     -->
   </repository>
 </repositories>
```

Comment: Yes this was tried, in the end we upgraded to umbraco 7. The new version of courier works like a dream.

Comment: Good news then! Yes, the new version does appear to be a bit more reliable